# opencv feature-matching er

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-extraction

I am working with opencv and added it to a c++ project. However, I have a problem with feature matching. the code is here:

```
cv::Ptr<Feature2D> f2d = xfeatures2d::SIFT::create();
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;
Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;

f2d->detectAndCompute(img_Org_Y_mat, Mat(), keypoints_1, descriptors_1);
f2d->detectAndCompute(img_Rec_Y_mat, Mat(), keypoints_2, descriptors_2);

vector<DMatch> matches;
BFMatcher matcher(NORM_L2);

matcher.match(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches);
```

I have a problem with last line which is:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (masks.size() == imageCount) in 
cv::DescriptorMatcher::checkMasks, file C:\Opencv2\opencv 
master\modules\features2d\src\matchers.cpp, line 617
```

and in the program it writes:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF803FA9E08 in TAppEncoder.exe: Microsoft C++ 
exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000CE624E9050.
```

Comment: This error says that mask which is normally 4th parameter to matcher.match has different size than imageCount. Since you are not passing anything as mask i would assume than you either forgot to recompile project after removing that parameter, or using old version of opencv. Which version of opencv do you use?

Comment: I use Opencv 3.3 and I  know nothing about the mask. I change it to noArray  or Mat() , but still have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this question.And i has solved it but i am not sure that this solution will be suitable to this question. I will share my solution.

I have add some .lib files which are needed in release model such as opencv_bgsegm341.lib to "Additional Dependencies" by mistake.

After i delete them, the program run successfully.

I hope this will do some help to you.